# Версии PHP в OpenServer

Tags: php, phpstorm, консоль

у меня такой вопрос, недавно настраивал CLI для PhpStorm и наткнулся на папку php в файлах OpenServer, увидел там версии PHP начиная с 5.0 заканчивая 7.3
Вопрос заключается в следующем: Могу ли я удалить старые версии PHP, не пропадет функционал у интерпретатора?

Comment: Вопрос, зачем? Если лишние 100 мб. спасут мир то да конечно. Просто если вам вдруг понадобится создать профиль для запуска старого проекта который не работает с 7+ то придется переустанавливать Openserver

Comment: 1) Можете. 2) Пропадет как минимум поддержка удаленных версий

Comment: 5.6 оставьте на всякий случай, остальное можете грохать, наверное.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ